# c# ClientCertificate is blank

Tags: c#, ssl, client-certificates

I am attempting to pass a certificate from a client program to a server program. On the client side I create an HttpWebRequest object and adding the certificate as follows.

```
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("Test.cer");
HttpWebRequest mainRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:443");
mainRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

I then perform the request using GetResponse()

On the server side, I attempt to access the certificate as follows.

```
byte[] cer = HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate;
```

This array is always byte[0] whenever I look at it however.

Both programs on running on the same box, requesting and listening. 
I have use mmc to import the certificate to both my Personal and Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder.

I'm stumped as to why the certificate is not being passed. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In case of IIS/web server did you configure server to require/accept certificates? If "server program" is some sort of homegrown application there is no way to guess without more information about it.

Comment: The "server program" is simply listening for a connection on certain ports. This is all being run on a single box right now. I'm not incredibly knowledgeable with networks, is IIS something that I need for this testing?

Comment: Unlikely to be answered as is. So you have custom "server program" to listen for connections... You'll need to sort out how it configures channel and if it actually cares about certs and if it actually set up `HttpContext.Current`... than update this/ask new question(s). You may want to check out [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class for sample of listener and see if stream's `RemoteCertificate` is what you are after.